# Not getting reCAPTCHA for Android images on some devices

Tags: android, android-studio, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to implement Google reCAPTCHA for Android. The problem I'm facing is I'm not able to see reCAPTCHA images, physical Android devices are directly getting success response whereas emulators are getting the reCAPTCHA images. Does anyone know how exactly Google reCAPTCHA for Android works ?!

Comment: Hello. Have you read this guide? https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha

Comment: Hi, I actually went through that guide and did the same thing. The issue is I'm getting the images on Emulators, but on actual Android Phones, I'm not able to get the challenge images. The challenges are automatically getting solved.